# $4p+1$ is perfect cube, sum of all possible $p$ values?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

This is a problem from a math Olympiad.

> $p$ is a positive prime number such that $4p+1$ is a perfect cube. What is the sum of all possible values of $p$?

I have done this by trial-error and brute-force method.

I simply went through every integer cube and tried to find out the p.

$4p+1=(positive integer)^3$

$p=\frac{(positive integer)^3-1}{4}$

$p = \frac{(5)^3-1}{4}$
starting from 1, I kept on plugging numbers to find p

I discovered that the only time $p$ is a prime number is when $4p+1=(5)^3$.
$p = 31$ then.

And $4p+1$ is a cube, is only true for $5$, $5+4$, $5+4+4$, and so on.

I hope I've made my attempts clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note $p = 2$ doesn't work so $p$ is an odd prime. Also, let the positive integer being cubed be $j$. You then have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
4p + 1 & = j^3 \\
4p & = j^3 - 1 \\
4p & = (j - 1)(j^2 + j + 1) \\
4p & = (j - 1)((j + 1)(j) + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note that $(j + 1)(j) + 1$ is always odd. Thus, since $(j + 1)(j) + 1 \gt 1$, plus $p$ is an odd prime and is the only odd factor on the LHS, this means $(j + 1)(j) + 1 = p$, which then gives $j - 1 = 4 \implies j = 5$. This shows the *only* solution where $p$ is a prime is $p = (6)(5) + 1 = 31$, as you've already determined.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it by a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $a$ is odd number.

Then rewrite your equation:

\begin{equation}
p=\frac{a^3-1}{4}=\frac{(a-1)(a^2+a+1)}{4}.
\end{equation}

$(a^2+a+1)$ is odd, thus 4 should divide $(a-1)$. Let $a=4k+1$, then

\begin{equation}
p=k(16k^2+12k+3)
\end{equation}

Now you need to take into account that $p$ is prime and and find only possible value $k=1$.